# Code To Add INDEX-MATCH Dynamic Range Formula To Workbook Named Ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I have the following named ranges (some of which are INDEX/MATCH dynamic ranges) and their accompanying formulas that are present in my workbook's Name Manager:

- Q1_BusinessWorkd_ID ='Q1 Data'!$C$35:INDEX('Q1 Data'!$G$35:$G$1048576,MATCH("zzzzz",'Q1 Data'!$C$35:$C$1048576,1)-1)
- Q1_Data ='Q1 Data'!$B$35:INDEX('Q1 Data'!$CF$35:$CF$1048576,MATCH("zzzzz",'Q1 Data'!$C$35:$C$1048576,1))
- Q1_Data_Start ='Q1 Data'!$B$35
- Q1_Row1_Column_Formulas ='Q1 Data'!$H$35:$CF$35
- Q1_Vlookup_Data ='Q1 Data'!$C$35:INDEX('Q1 Data'!$CF$35:$CF$1048576,MATCH("zzzzz",'Q1 Data'!$C$35:$C$1048576,1))

The formulas that DON'T contain the INDEX and MATCH statements can be added to the workbook's Named Ranges using the folowing VBA code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Q1_Data_Start", RefersTo:="='Q1 Data'!$B$35"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Q1_Row1_Column_Formulas", RefersTo:="='Q1 Data'!$H$35:$CF$35"
```

However, the formulas that contain the INDEX and MATCH statements generate a compile syntax error.  I have no idea how to correct the syntax of the INDEX - MATCH formulas to not generate the syntax error.

Anyone know how to correct this problem?

Comment: You need to escape any double quotes in a string by doubling them up so (eg) `MATCH("zzzzz",` should be `MATCH(""zzzzz"",`

Comment: Thanks, Tim!  I forgot all about that.  That's exactly what the debugger reported as the problem  I'll try the double quotes and report back.

Comment: Tim - Your solution worked perfectly.  If you want to answer the question with your comment I'll award the answer to you.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape any double quotes in a string by doubling them up so (eg)

```
...MATCH("zzzzz", ...
```

should be

```
...MATCH(""zzzzz"", ...
```